# Static code analysis using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: jetbrains-ide, static-code-analysis

How can I get the static code analysis level of below code using IntelliJ IDEA.

```
int x = 1;
if( x == 1) {
System.out.println(x);

}
else{
System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: it's a mistake. not coverage. but analysis

Answer (score 3):

Create a project and a java class and then put your code inside a main method such as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 1;
    if( x == 1) {
        System.out.println(x);

    }
    else{
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Then you can do static code analysis. Select "Analyze" in the top menu bar > Click "Inspect Code" from the dropdown menu.

This will bring up a window that allows you to "Specify Inspection Skope". Choose "File '[*projectname*] - *locationtofile*'"

*projectname* and *locationtofile* will be automatically shown based upon what you have called your java class.

Then click "Ok". This will launch the static code analysis. At the bottom of the screen you will then see a window appear that says "Inspection results for... *your project name* "

In this window you will be able to see the probable bugs and other detected issues that IntelliJ has found.

Hopefully this helps!